# Потоки, WaitForMultipleObject

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Здравствуйте, использование WaitForMultipleObject(....) только для массива дескрипторов? Или можно использовать для разных дескрипторов? Просто не совсем понимаю синтаксис.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для массива конечно. Указывается массив, его длина и как ждать: одного или всех.

А что значит для разных? Они и есть в массиве разные...